# vue.js move method from .vue to vuex store

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

Scenario:
in `user.js` I have:

```
import * as mutationTypes from "../mutation-types";
import {user} from "./user_data";

export const state = {
  user: user
  ...
}

export const getters = {
  user: (state) => state.user,
...
};

export const mutations = {
  [mutationTypes.SET_USER]: (state, payload) => {
    state.user=payload;  
  },
  ...
  );
  
  export const actions = {
  setUser: ({ commit }, payload) => {
    commit(mutationTypes.SET_USER, payload);
  },
  ...
  );
  
  export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions,
};
```

now I want to move a method used in several pages from the .vue pages to this store page:
so I added to user.js actions the following:

```
getUser: async ({ commit }) =>{
    this.user.loading=true;    
    try{
        const res = await this.$http.post('/ajax/settings/settings_read.php');
        if (res.data.errorid=='0')
        { 
          let payload=res.data.user;
          commit(mutationTypes.SET_USER, payload);
        }
        else
        {
          this.$router.push('/auth/login').catch(() => {});
        }      
    } catch(e)
    {
      console.log(e);
    }
    this.user.loading=false;    
},
```

and in .vue pages (actually I tried may different solutions adding async/await in several places)

```
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
...
  created(){
      this.$store.dispatch("getUser"); 
  },
```

but does not work.

Can suggest the right way to move a method to vuex store?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about the not working part? Do you get an error? Does anything appear to happen? Does nothing happen at all?

Comment: This may not directly be your problem, but you're double-exporting your store state/ getters/ mutations/ actions. You should *either* export the store properties individually, *or* export them as an object, but not both.

Comment: @zcoop98 thanks. you mean that I should remove all  the `export` before `const` or fully remove `export default {  state,  getters,  mutations,  actions,}; `
?

Comment: I think you could do either actually; I'm more familiar with exporting the object, but whatever's more familiar to you works fine :)

Comment: oh.. how can remove both :-(
Actually I'm not very familiar with any solution

Anyway, the error I get now (after some changes) is `Cannot read property '$http' of undefined` where `this.$http.post(...)` is `axios`, but `axios` is not defined in this `user.js` but in `main.js`

Comment: Well, then simply `import http from "axios"` inside `user.js` and use it `http.post(...)`

Comment: hmm but `$http` is defined as `Vue.prototype.$http = Axios;` in `main.js` and from what I understood should be available throughout the project .. anyway I will try. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this.user is reference to user in your state, hence

```
 this.user.loading=true;
```

would change the state outside the mutation.